# Proving that $L$ is a linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $P$ be the subspace of $v$. space $V$ and $Q$ be the subspace of $v$. space $W$ over the same field $K$. $V$ is finite-dimensional. 
If $\dim(P) + \dim(Q)=\dim(V)$ prove that there is a linear transformation $ L:V\rightarrow W$  for which $\ker(L)=P$ and $\text{Im}(L)=Q.$

I really don't have an idea where to start here.
So $dim(P)=k$ and $dim(Q) =n-k$
I can use any vector $v$ from $V$ and  a scalar "$a1,a2,...,an$" from $K$ and represent v as an linear combination v = a1*e1 + · · · + an*en.
$L(v) = L(a1e1 + · · · + anen) = a1L(e1) + · · · + anL(en) = a1*0 + · · · +ak+1fk+1+· · ·+ anfn,$

Is this good

Comment: Please edit your post and use LATEX.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start with a basis $\{e_1,e_2,\ldots, e_k\}$ of $P$ and extend it to basis $\{e_1,e_2,\ldots e_n\}$ of $V$. Now choose a basis $\{f_1,f_2,\ldots, f_{n-k}\}$ of $Q$ and define $L:V\to W$ by
$$
L(e_i) = \begin{cases}
0 &: 1\leq i\leq k \\
f_{i-k} &: k+1\leq  n
\end{cases}
$$
and extend this linearly. Now check that this satisfies the required conditions.

Comment: So dim(P)=k and dim(Q) =n-k
I can use any vector v from V and  a scalar "a1,a2,...,an" from K and represent v as an linear combination v = a1*v1 + · · · + an*vn.